# Cannot set Breakpoints in Specific Functions by Lauterbach debugger

Tags: c, embedded, powerpc, trace32, lauterbach

When debugging code with lauterbach, some functions which are present and displayed in Trace32 cannot put any breakpoints inside them and when trying to put a Breakpoint at the line which this function is called it is not hit (i.e line is skipped)

Comment: A lot depends on the way the file-under-test was compiled.  The file-under-test must be compiled with the full debug info included. (with the gcc compiler, use a parameter '-g' debug family.  Also do not use any parameter in the '-O' optimization family.)   It greatly helps if the debugger can also see the source code for the file-under-test

Answer (score 1):

Compilation optimization cause such behavior. The reason is that the compiler had omitted the function because of missing reference.
If you switch off the optimization (inside the IDE or command line) you will be able to place brakepoint (although unecessarily because execution will never hit it, that's why had the compiler put it off).